# Is it possible to define multiple PHP file templates in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

When creating a new file in Eclipse, I select "New PHP File", the source for which is located in `Eclipse` / `Preferences` / `PHP` / `Code Style` / `Code Templates` / `Simple php file`. I want to create multiple "New PHP File" entries for each of the API methods in our system, for instance "New GET File", "New POST File", etc. Is this possible? I've tried exporting, editing, and importing xml files, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible see also official eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318164

Comment: Those who would like this feature added back in (yes back in, it used to exist) please vote on the bug report linked above.